# (не) многопоточность в php

Tags: php

Была задача выполнять длительные операции не дожидаясь завершения текущей операции.

так как в php многопоточности нет, я сделал так:

```
foreach ($operations as $operation) {
    shell_exec("php script.php ".$operation['id']." 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &");
}
```

Таким образом на каждую операцию одновременно запускается один и тот же скрипт который работает с переданной ему операцией `$operation['id']`

И это очень хорошо для меня работает.

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли какие-то недостатки такого решения?

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию!

Comment: Кроме сложностей с отслеживанием таких вот порожденных процессов - да вроде и нет, закономерный подход для пхп :)

Answer (score 1):

Это вполне рабочий способ, но (как уже сказал человечек в комментариях) могут возникнуть сложности если понадобится отслеживать порождённые процессы. Также, для ознакомления, хочу рассказать о двух модулях:

- [PThreads](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pthreads.php): Модуль, предоставляющий объектно-ориентированный API для работы с многопоточностью в PHP (он нравится мне гораздо больше чем следующий (хоть и "считается неподдерживаемым и мёртвым")). Подробнее см. тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.pthreads.php
- [Parallel](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.parallel.php): Модуль параллельного выполнения для PHP ≥ 7.2.0. Подробнее см. тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.parallel.php